# How can I call an API resource in C# with a path parameter containing a slash character

Tags: c#

I want to create a simple Windows service in C# that calls an API REST resource periodically.

The resource has a path parameter in its URL, and the variable I want to send has slashes "/".

How cant I make the call without it looking for the worng resource because of the slash?

This is my code:

```
httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(URI + Param); //Param : "F51D0_TX_PULSE_300_009/IDX2"  and URI : "http://bla.net:8080/meter/"
httpWebRequest.ContentType = ContentType;
httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("KeyId", Key);
httpWebRequest.Timeout = m_TimeOutForecast;
httpWebRequest.Proxy = Proxy;
using(var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream())) {
  streamWriter.Write(bodyRequest);
  streamWriter.Flush();
  streamWriter.Close();
}

using(httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse) httpWebRequest.GetResponse()) {
  if (httpResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) {
    using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream())) {
      responseFromAPI = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a script that you are using, most of the times, the helpers here want to see what you have to help you make it better, they like to see how it works, and how it errors, maybe you can update your question

Comment: Is this `batch` or `bash` related?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of details. Edited my post

Comment: Url encode it...

Comment: I tried using `%F`, but it doesn't work